# Can I use a program via java?

Tags: java, image

My question is simple:
 Is it possible to use a program via Java? Meaning, can I for example code in java exactly what I want my Microsoft Word file do? Add paragraphs, lists,import a picture, etc?

Comment: Depends on the program

Comment: Short answer is yes.

Comment: Please see [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question/7274)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes. Some programs allow you to use scripts and such, that is the beauty of open source software.

To actually edit the document you can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) which is an API for Microsoft Documents. Granted it cannot handle .docx but simple text documents. You may also want to take a look at [docx4java](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j) which supports .docx, .pptx and .xlsx files.